# Unable to write checkpoint information to logging table

Tags: mysql, pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

All my jobs running in the repository is failing with the below error

```
2017/09/22 06:18:52 - job_load - Unable to write checkpoint information to logging table
2017/09/22 06:18:52 - job_load -
2017/09/22 06:18:52 - job_load - Couldn't execute SQL: LOCK TABLES null WRITE
2017/09/22 06:18:52 - job_load -
2017/09/22 06:18:52 - job_load - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'null WRITE' at line 1
```

I do have the `KETTLE_CHECKPOINT_LOG_TABLE=pentaho_checkpoint_log` in my kettle.properties and the corresponding table exists in the MySQL server. All my jobs used to run fine but all of a sudden they stopped functioning with the same error.

All my jobs and transformations doesnt have this value filled in the Logging section and hence it used to default the values from the `kettle.properties`

When I force the job by providing this variable, it works. But not sure why this problem occurred out of no where. There were no changes to `kettle.properties` or my jobs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with shared.xml where someone has changed it by mistake. The logging was expecting the following sequencing to be present

```
<attribute><code>EXTRA_OPTION_MYSQL.AUTOINCREMENT_SQL_FOR_BATCH_ID</code><attribute>UPDATE log_counter SET ID&#x3d;LAST_INSERT_ID&#x28;ID&#x2b;1&#x29;</attribute></attribute>
```